# how to delete duplicate values in mysql table

Tags: php, mysql

I have column in mysql table (`my_sale_time`) of type `timestamp`....infact the rows value look like this

```
2010-12-01 14:38:07
2010-12-01 17:14:18
...
```

so what i need mysql query to delete those value whose date is repeated multiple times in table.....as i mentioned in sample `sale_time_value`.....only **date** is repeated with same value but **time** is different....so i want to get all rows, date is repeated multiple times and delete duplicate dates

Comment: First you need to decide the criteria for which row of the duplicates you want to keep since all columns are not exact dupes.

Comment: I assume all other columns are identical and it's only the time part of the timestamp that is different?

Comment: do you have an auto-increment column on the table in question that the dups exist?

Answer (score 7):

The basic principle of deleting duplicate rows:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmptbl AS SELECT DISTINCT * FROM my_sale_time;
DELETE FROM my_sale_time;
INSERT INTO my_sale_time SELECT * FROM tmptbl;
```

You may have to specify columns and WHERE clauses (I didn't really understand your criteria).
And of course you should test-run it on a development server and don't forget to run it as a single transaction with locked tables.

Comment: okay i will tell you what i need,,,,,i have column 'sale_time' and it has dateandtime values stored.....so, what i want is, i want to delete only date which is repeated more then 1,,,,,here is the example : 2010-12-01 14:38:07,2010-12-01 17:14:18. if you notice to this values, u can find date is same but time is different so any how i want to delete this type of values from table...how?

Comment: Run `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmptbl AS SELECT DISTINCT DATE(sale_time), * FROM my_sale_time` and check if `tmptbl` contains the rows you want.

Comment: okay i will tell you what i need,,,,,i have column 'sale_time' and it has dateandtime values stored.....so, what i want is, i want to delete only date which is repeated more then 1,,,,,here is the example : 2010-12-01 14:38:07,2010-12-01 17:14:18. if you notice to this values, u can find date is same but time is different so any how i want to delete this type of values from table...how?

Comment: you have your answer. Don't start with "feed me cookies now"

Comment: @shahid: Please stop posting the same comment again. It doesn't make things clearer!

Answer (score 0):

If you have an auto_increment field, use this:

```
DELETE FROM
    `mytable`
WHERE
    `my_auto_increment_field` NOT IN (
        SELECT
            MAX(`my_auto_increment_field`)
        GROUP BY
            `my_sale_time`
    );
```